# Can citizens from the trusted districts move to live in the Capitol?

Tags: the-hunger-games

I understand the other districts can't, because during the dark wars the Capitol thinks those districts were the rebels (and yes, even Districts 1 and 2 had rebels). But would citizens of District 1 and 2, who the Capitol citizens or particularly Snow knows quite well, be not allowed to move to the Capitol and/or participate in Snow's rebel punishment known as "the Hunger Games"?

Comment: @Hannah Not a duplicate, that's the converse.